# Initializing nested structures in C: an alternate approach (reminding quite a bit of JS object literals)

Tags: c, nested, structure, standards, iso

Not long ago I read about this elegant way of nested structure initialization in someone else's code, however I have never found any *documentation* about this particular kind of approach. In a nutshell, it can entirely do without `{`  `}` braces, except for the ordinary brace after the `=` operator.

The specialty in here (at least for me) is that **initializations start with a dot operator**, which is a syntax that reminded me a lot of object literals declaration in JavaScript (cf. there)

However, I'm wondering: has this always been allowed in ISO-C? It looks entirely new to me, and that may as well be, since I still code a pre-1999 C style and have never occupied myself too much with the new C (*not* C++) features.
Nevertheless, I'd like to know about sources where this kind of initialization is documented and how it is called.
Enough of my talk, here is the code snippet (albeit stripped down a lot for simplicity's sake):

```
typedef struct plugin_s {

    /* plugin version */
    int16_t version_major;
    int16_t version_minor;

} plugin_t; 

typedef struct example_plugin_s {

  plugin_t stdplugin;
  int (*is_ongoing) (void); 
  int (*is_stalled) (void); 

  /* lots more stuff here, which is not relevant at this point */

} example_plugin_t; 


/*
    now the interesting bit is coming...
    again: no braces used while initializing values
    (as you would usually expect)!
*/

 static example_plugin_t stdplugin = {
     .stdplugin.version_major = 1,
     .stdplugin.version_minor = 0,
     .is_ongoing = funcref1,
     .is_stalled = funcref2
 };
```

Comment: Search for "designated initializers", and you'll find something. However, C is not a language with an OOP syntax. I hope you realize what you're doing with `stdplugin.is_ongoing` and other so-called member functions, though. After all, how does funcref1 know which object it has? C doesn't have a `this` or `self` like C++ or Objective-C/Python respectively, nor anything like prototyping in JS.

Comment: Oh, that "designated initializers" may already become a good trace to pursue. It's always easier once you know how the thing is named. Thanks! Looks I was RIGHT after all! That's indeed __C99 standard__ and apparently unknown to "classic" C89/90, hence "beyond my scope" (and, by the way, even beyond the scope of MSVC 2008 :)) http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html -- No wonder it looked so surprisingly new to me. Here I've found another excellent elaboration on the subject: http://nickdesaulniers.github.io/blog/2013/07/25/designated-initialization-with-pointers-in-c/

Comment: It is very useful. Unfortunately, C++ didn't carry it over, but in C++, structures that aren't `extern "C"` are classes anyway and should use constructors, which provide similar functionality. Since MSVC sticks to C89, it isn't really suited for modern C programming. It is probably intended for bridging low-level code that doesn't need class overhead with C++ code. This is why I advocate moving away from MSVC if programming in C. There is a lot that is useful in C99 that you're missing if you stick to MSVC.

Comment: I'm definitely not sticking to it, but think about writing portable code that's supposed to compile fine in both GNU C __and__ MSVC. Unfortunately, AFAIR nearly everywhere, programmers in general currently have to do without C99 in these cases. Unless moon phases will be fortunate enough someday so that MS can finally convince their inner self to implement the *entire* C99 stuff, not just a ridiculous slice of it.